# Some doubts about memory-retain in ios applicato?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory, retain

1. What is the need for retain an `NSObject` in ios application?
2. What is the difference between `retainCount==1`,`retainCount=2`,.....etc?
3. How properties can handle retaining and releasing instance variable?
4. when i am retain/releasing `NSObject` ,the retain count increate/decrease by one, what happens exactly in memory?

Comment: Please read this regarding retainCount: http://www.friday.com/bbum/2011/12/18/retaincount-is-useless/

Comment: Thanks to much, this is very nice document...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Retaining an object indicates that you are taking ownership of that object. So you have to release it once after you are done with it.
2. retainCount = 1 indicates that it is being strongly referenced from one place. If retainCount = 2, then it is being strongly referenced from two places.
3. Properties, depending on whether it is a retain, copy or assign property, handles memory management differently
4. Retain count only tells us how many string references are there for the object. As ling as it is greater than 0, the object is not removed from memory. Once it becomes 0, the obj is removed from memory (dealloc of tht object is called)

**EDIT**:

1. If it is a retain property, each time you set a retain property using the '.', then the old value is released, new value is retained and assigned to the property. The same happens with copy, just that the new value is sent a copy instead of retain. If it is an assign property, the new value is directly assigned to the property (no release, no retain)

Comment: If retain count increase/decrease by one  any change in memory?

Comment: No change in memory as long as the retain count is greater than 0.

Comment: Strong reference is when you inti/alloc an obj, or retain or copy and obj. In this case it means that, as long as this object is being referenced, the obj will not be removed from the memory. Say NSString *str1 = [[NSString alloc] init].. so here, till we release str1, the memory is not cleaned. So it is a strong ref. Same happens when you do NSString *str2 = [str1 retain]. So in this case, str1 ans str2 have to release, for the memory to be cleared. So there are two strong referenced to the same memory.

Comment: what the  use retain count in Concurrency program?

Comment: if it is NSSTring *str1 = [[NSSTring alloc] init]; (here ref count = 1  ==> means memory has one strong ref). When i do this: NSString *str2= str (no retain/copy), this is a weak reference, ie if i release str1, then memory is released, and str2 also will be invalid.

Comment: In some time I want to explicitly retain NSObject else getting EXCE_BADACCESS why?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6683/discussion-between-shanti-k-and-musthafa-p-p)

Comment: i invited u for a chat, we can discus it further there

Comment: where u invite is it gmail/stackoverflow?

Comment: In StackOverflow, thr is a link above in my comments only.. click on tht. "let us continue this discussion in chat".. click on tht comment

Comment: 1 and 3 are correct.  2 is nonsense and thinking like that will lead to crashy code.  The absolute retain count of an object is meaningless and does not indicate the number of strong references at all.  The retain count of an object will never be zero.  Read the documents Omid posted.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701259/why-we-are-checking-if-cell-nil-in-uitableviewcontroller/9701424#comment12329906_9701424