# Why we are checking if (cell == nil) in UITableViewController?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, cell

I am trying to implement UITableView based Application.For that I select UITableViewStyle is Group.In my TableView their is **15** section each section having 1 row.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 15;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return 1;
}
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section==12) 
    {
        return 120;
    }
    else
    {
        return 60;
    }

}
```

I want add a UITextView on Section **12**

For that i did following code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];



    }
    if ([indexPath section] == 12) 
    {
        if([indexPath row]==0)
        {
            descriptionTextField=[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 8, 290, 106)];
            descriptionTextField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0];   
            descriptionTextField.backgroundColor=[UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor];

            [descriptionTextField setDelegate:self];
            [descriptionTextField setTag:2];
            [descriptionTextField setText:@"Enter Location Description."];

            descriptionTextField.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
            descriptionTextField.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeyNext;


            descriptionTextField.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
            descriptionTextField.editable=YES;
            descriptionTextField.autocapitalizationType=UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
            descriptionTextField.autocorrectionType=UITextAutocorrectionTypeDefault;
            descriptionTextField.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;

            UIToolbar*  keboardToolBar=[[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 32)];

            UIBarButtonItem *extra=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
            UIBarButtonItem *Done=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(keyboardDoneButtonActin:)];
            [Done setWidth:65.0f];
            [keboardToolBar setItems:[[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:extra,Done, nil]autorelease] ];
            [extra release];
            [Done release];

            [keboardToolBar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
            [keboardToolBar setAlpha:.70];
            [descriptionTextField setInputAccessoryView:keboardToolBar];
            [descriptionTextField setTag:101];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:descriptionTextField];
            [descriptionTextField release];
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

In the initil stage the table view like this

[image]

if i am scrolling tableview up and down , then the uitextView section changed and it will display multiple location.

[image]

I can't understand my fault, why this happend?

if am implementing the above code in side the if(cell==nil)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    if ([indexPath section] == 12) 
    {
        if([indexPath row]==0)
        {
           **/* implemention  all code here*/**

             [cell.contentView addSubview:descriptionTextField];
            [descriptionTextField release];
        }
    }

    return cell;
```

}

UITextView  not disply, i think it is not allocating.

so what is the difference between code implementing in 
if (cell == nil) 
{ 
inside 
}

if (cell == nil) 
{
}
out side

Comment: only difference is that when u wrote the code inside cell==nil it will work only once at starting if u write out side it will create every time when the view load

Comment: why section value changed if scrolling tableview . if i wright code out side?

Comment: one more thing u can do in your code set one tag value for textview and then write this code  [[cell.contentView viewWithTag:100+indexPath.row] removeFromSuperview]; 100+index.row is tag value

Comment: because it uses same cell view again and you do not need to initialize all the cells in the tableview. The cells that are visible are initialized. Also your memory will be remain in control @Mustafa

Comment: How to over come this problem

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",indexPath.row];

// Dequeue or create a cell of the appropriate type.
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

This can be used instead of

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

this is the simple example to write inside the cell ==nill

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
// Dequeue or create a cell of the appropriate type.
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell= nil;
if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    [[cell.contentView viewWithTag:100+indexPath.row] removeFromSuperview]; 

    UIView *selectview = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, 30)];
    [selectview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"strip_s12A-1_h.png"]]];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectview;
    [selectview release];

    UILabel *cellTitle=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 0, 300, 30)];
    //cellTitle.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
    [cellTitle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [cellTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" size:17]];
    [cellTitle setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    cellTitle.tag = 100+indexPath.row;

        cellTitle.text= [[[cellArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Des2"];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:cellTitle];

    [cellTitle release];
}
return cell;
     }
```

i think will be enough right

Comment: Is it possible to  create UITextView inside if(cell==nil)

Comment: i did not understand why section value change, if we scrolling table view.

Comment: If i getting problem, can i connect to u? Because, i want to leave now. i want to check little more.

Comment: In the UITabBarController one of the tabBarItem is UINavigationController with RootViewController(UITableVIewController).THe scrolling property of tableView is enabled.When select for one cell for the editing purpose the the tableview not Scrolled. the Key board will hide cell. In Normal case(with out UITabBarController) it work fine. This error is related ti UITababrController?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8898/discussion-between-krishna-and-musthafa-p-p)

Answer (score 3):

The test `if (cell == nil)` handles the case where there are no reusable cells to dequeue, in which case you must create a new cell.  When you create the new cell, you are responsible for constructing its view hierarchy.

Comment: @MusthafaPP The cells are recycled, rather then instantiating new ones. The reason: performance, speed. Most often in [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), we make new instances (objects) as needed. But instantiating a fresh object has some overhead, takes a bit of time. In rare instances, such as UITableView, we need the utmost in performance. Recycling an existing object, while resetting its key properties/variables appropriate for the fresh use, saves enough time to warrant the bother. So, if you have a cell available, re-use it. Else, make a new instance.